Hibernate Shared Primark Key with additional column
I am in process of upgrading a old application from Hibernate 3 xml oriented to Hibernate 5 Annotation oriented. Could you suggest on proper annotation configuration for below tables
Parent - Id( ID is primark key)
Child- ID, Parent ID( ID is shared primary key of Parent and Parent ID is also ID)
Below is the current xml configuration
Parent Hibernate xml:
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="au.Parent">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="Child" property-ref="parent" class="au.Child"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Child Hibernate xml:
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="au.Child">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="id">
      <generator class="foreign">
        <param name="property">parent</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one not-null="true" unique="true" column="parentId" lazy="no-proxy" cascade="all" name="parent"/>  
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

I have converted to below annotations
Child Table
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Child  {
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId",referencedColumnName = "id",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private Parent parent;


    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Parent parentPK;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;



    public PropertySchedule getParentPK() {
        return parentPK;
    }

    public void setParentPK(Parent parentPK) {
        this.parentPK = parentPK;
        
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public PropertySchedule getParent() {
        return propertySchedule;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    
    
}

Parent Annotations:
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Parent extends BaseValueObject {

    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Child child; // parent

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parentPK")
    private Child childPK;// parent

    
    public Child getChild() {
        return this.child;
    }
    public void setChild(Child child) {
        this.child = child;

    }

    public Child getChildPK() {
        return childPK;
    }

    public void setChildPK(Child childPK) {
    
        this.childPK = childPK;
    }

    
}

While saving we save using the child entity rather than the Parent entity
Old code: Couldnt progress as it says parent cant be null
        synchronized (ChildServiceImpl.class) {
            
            
            child= childDao.save(child);
            childDao.flush();
        
            return child;
        }
    }

Changed to below code:
public Child create(Child child) {
        
        

            Parent parent = new Parent();

            Parent =childDao.save(parent);
            childDao.flushandClear();
            child.setParentPK(Parent );
            child.setParent(Parent );
            child = childDao.save(child);
            childDao.flushandClear();
        
            return child ;
        }
    }

But Now its creating two Parent records for every save and inserting one for ID and other for Parent ID columns in Child table. I need only record. Could you please suggest
